# I backed-up my site and now my views are broken

Tags: views

My site recently got deleted by a possible hack. I backed up the database and the folders, but now my views are not working; everything else works.

The fields are showing this in admin/build/views/edit/nameofview:

> Broken/missing handler: node_data_field_guru_photo > field_guru_photo_fid
>       Broken/missing handler: node > title
>       Broken/missing handler: views > nothing
>       Broken/missing handler: node_revisions > body
>       Broken/missing handler: node_data_field_guru_link > field_guru_link_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is looking for fields that do no longer exists?
Have you changed anything in your content types maybe?